# Mac won't install updates

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, software-update, auto-update

So the problem started around a month back when I was prompted if I'd like to restart my mac to install system updates. I proceeded with the restart and apple's logo along with a loader appeared. By mistake I pressed some key and the process was interrupted. Ever since, I see there's a pending update that has been downloaded but the updates don't just install no matter how much I restart.

Also I see there are some updates downloaded in /Library/Updates but I'm unable to delete them or install them. pasting a tree of /Library/Updates

```
➜  Updates tree --du -h
.
├── [ 4.4G]  001-12343
├── [ 4.5G]  001-22626
├── [ 4.4G]  061-94457
├── [ 2.8G]  061-96003
├── [1.1M]  ProductMetadata.plist
└── [ 819]  index.plist
```

My main concern for now is to get rid of these update files which are taking almost 15 gigs out of the 110 available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your terminal and enter `softwareupdate -l` to see the available updates. Use `softwareupdate -i -a` to download and install all available updates.